# How do I assign a variable to an established loop of two lists in Python?

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have the following for loop assigned to a set of two list indices in Python, and must set it to the variable "names_and_ranks". How would I do that from here?

```
for index in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]:
    print (city_indices[index]+".",city_names[index])
```

This prints as follows:

```
1. Buenos Aires
2. Toronto
3. Pyeongchang
4. Marakesh
5. Albuquerque
6. Los Cabos
7. Greenville
8. Archipelago Sea
9. Walla Walla Valley
10. Salina Island
11. Solta
12. Iguazu Falls
```

The original question was: "assign the variable names_and_ranks to a list, with each element equal to the city name and it's corresponding rank. For example, the first element would be, "1. Buenos Aires" and the second would be "2. Toronto". Use a for loop and the lists city_indices and city_names to accomplish this."

```
for index in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]:
    print (city_indices[index]+".",city_names[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two working solutions the first uses a traditional for loop and the second uses list comprehension:

```
city_indices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
city_names = [
    "Buenos Aires", "Toronto", "Pyeongchang", "Marakesh", "Albuquerque",
    "Los Cabos", "Greenville", "Archipelago Sea", "Walla Walla Valley",
    "Salina Island", "Solta", "Iguazu Falls"
]

# using a for loop
names_and_ranks = []
for index in range(12):
    names_and_ranks.append(f"{city_indices[index]}. {city_names[index]}")

# using list comprehension
names_and_ranks = [
    ". ".join([str(x) for x in item]) for item in zip(city_indices, city_names)
]
```